# jQuery works instead of $

Tags: plugins, jquery

I am using $ in my custom js file in a wordpress child theme.
But it says $ is not defined. But jQuery works fine. 
What is the reason? Is it because $ is used in newer version of jQUery and WP uses old version 1.12.4. Kindly correct me.

Kind Regards

Comment: Generall `jQuery` works better than `$` even when `$` works

Answer (score 1):

WP uses [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).  If you want to use $ instead of jQuery you have a couple options.

**Option #1 - use a self-invoking function:**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ...
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**Option #2 - Set noConflict():**

Add `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` at the top of your custom JS file.

Comment: WP sets `noConflict` automatically, you don't need to call it like that

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I know WP sets noConflict but it was my understanding because it sets it you need to also in your custom JS files.  I will have to look into this more, I've been using that for years

Comment: No, I've never had to specify no conflict, and just used `jQuery` as is, or done the function trick like your last code snippet

Comment: Im not sure why the downvote, my answer isnt worng.  Obviously you could just use jQuery but the OP said he is using $.  Doing what I said above will make his JS file work so he doesn't have to go through and change every $ to jQuery.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted, perhaps edit the answer to note that WP uses noConflict mode by default, hence why `$` isn't available, then provide your solutions. It could be that your answer was downvoted because it doesn't explain why `$` is unavailable

Answer (score 0):

As different JS Frameworks use the $ for it's functions (jQuery, MooTools), Wordpress loads jQuery in the "noConflict"-Mode, which means that it doesn't use the $ but only jQuery.

You can now

1. use jQuery instead of $
2. encapsule your calls like RiddleMeThis proposed

On a personal note: honestly, it's not that big a deal to replace the $ with jQuery, isn't it? ;)

Happy Coding!